# I'm testing a simple MILP program using cvxpy. However, the solver stops converging after I increase the number of variables slightly

Tags: python, cvxpy

The task is to place n number of non-overlapping segments into an interval, maximizing the total covered space inside the interval. This is a 1D toy problem to be extended for future "fitting boxes into a bigger box" kinds of problems.

The interval is defined as [x0, x1]. Each segment is defined by a starting xi and a width wi. The objective function is to maximize the sum of all widths, given some constraints.

There are straight forward constraints that keep all segments within the interval, and collisions constraints between segments to avoid overlaps. The collision constraints use binary helper variables.

```
import cvxpy as cp

# Problem set up
x0 = 2
x1 = 20
num_segments = 4

# Segment variables
X = cp.Variable(num_segments) # starting x's
W = cp.Variable(num_segments) # widths

# Constraints keeping segments in interval
constraints = [X + W <= x1, X >= x0, W >=1]

# Pairwise collision constraints
for i in range(num_segments-1):
    for j in range(i+1, num_segments):
        # Helper binary variables
        sigma_r = cp.Variable(boolean=True)
        sigma_l = cp.Variable(boolean=True)
        # segment i can be on the left or the right of segment j
        constraints += [X[i] - W[j] >= X[j]-4000*(1-sigma_r)]
        constraints += [X[i] + W[i] <= X[j]+4000*(1-sigma_l)]
        # require at least one sigma to be 1
        constraints += [sigma_r + sigma_l >= 1]

# maximize sum of widths
objective = cp.Maximize(cp.sum(W))

prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
prob.solve()
```

This works fine for num_segments up to 6, anything past that and the solver never converges. I feel this should not be a hard optimization for number of variables below 100. Any ideas what could be causing the issue? Should I be looking into other solvers?

Comment: Check which solver is used (verbose-mode). cvxpy brings only a toy-solver out of the box and the non-commercial alternatives will need special care during install (see docs).